# Incorrect SQL generated by Pomelo with MySQL and .NET Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been using .NET Core and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (v1.1.2, it is not the latest but I would prefer to stay on it for various reasons).

I was doing some refactoring of the model classes, creating a child-parent relationship (eg. Order has a Customer) and now when I run my project I get an exception

```
2019-09-16T12:36:49.8158085-07:00 0HLPQRKH27D40 [INF] Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], 

CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
INSERT INTO `Order`
DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); (6438bdd5)
2019-09-16T12:36:49.9249074-07:00 0HLPQRKH27D40 [ERR] An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
 (3b5ca34b)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT VALUES;
```

The problem seems to be the use of `default values` in  `insert into 'order' default values;` because MySQL [doesn't support that syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).  My dev version of mysql is 5.1, but that doesn't seem to matter since it doesn't seem to be in later versions.

I looked (naively) at the Pomelo source but only found usage of "DEFAULT VALUES" in a unit test.

Comment: What operating is generating the exception? Adding new `Order`? If yes, looks like all `Order` properties use default values. Make sure at least one property/column have no `HasDefaultValue` or `HasDefaultValueSql` setting (or whatever it was called in 1.1.2) and also is not auto generated by the database. For more concrete answer, post the `Order` entity class and relevant fluent configuration.

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev, I was mapping properties in Order to another object's properties, like `public string PropA => obj.ProbA` and when I stopped doing that and changed it to long form using getters and setters it started working.  If you care to write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Oh, actually using `=>` in the properties removes them from the DB table, I hadn't realised that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mapping properties in Order to another object's properties, eg

```
public string PropA => obj.ProbA
```

and when I stopped doing that and changed it to long form using getters and setters it started working.